# Resizing ViewController to accommodate the keyboard

Tags: uiviewcontroller, keyboard, resize, uitextfield

This is for XCode, creating an app for iPhone.

Ok, so I am creating a sign up screen using a **UIViewController**. It has about 6 **textfields** on it so they accommodate most of the page. problem is when I wish to type data in to them using the keyboard, the keyboard blocks the view of the lower **textfields**.

Is there any way I can resize the **UIViewController** for when the keyboard appears and then returns to normal once the keyboard is dismissed so that I can see the **textfields**?

Answer (score 1):

Follow this example given in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html) (go to *"Moving Content That Is Located Under the Keyboard"* section). It's works really great for me, hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah that documentation didn't help me too much, im very much a beginner at app making so Im not too sure of what im doing. Do you know of any other tutorials??